# Symfony 6 Liipimagine imagine_filter doesn't work

Tags: symfony, twig, liipimaginebundle

I am trying to use the bundle Liipimagine in a Symfony 6 project for the first time and I have a problem.
I created a filter in the liip_imagine.yaml

```
liip_imagine:
    # valid drivers options include "gd" or "gmagick" or "imagick"
    driver: "gd"

    filter_sets:
        livres:
            quality: 75
            filters: 
                fixed: 
                    width: 120
                    height: 90
```

When I want to use my filter, if in my twig view I use this syntax :

```
<img src="{{ asset('assets/images/photographier.jpg') | imagine_filter('livres') }}" alt="photo appareil photo" class="rounded-3 mb-2">
```

the picture is well display

But if I use this syntax for another image :

```
<img class="img-fluid" src="/uploads/images/{{ exposition.image1|imagine_filter('livres') }}" alt="photo pour l'exposition {{ exposition.titre }}">
```

it doesn't work. Nothing is displayed and I have this error in the console :
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

If I don't use the imagine_filter the two pictures are displayed.

I think the problem comes from the way I integrate the imagine_filter in the  but I can't find a solution.
Does somebody have an idea ?

Thanks for any help

Comment: I found that when I use the second syntax the images are not created in the media/cache/resolve directory. Do you no why ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in the src attribute.
you should write :

```
src="{{'relative/path/to/your/image'|imagine_filter('livres') }}"
```

If your image is uploaded through your app, I highly  recommend you to use [vich uploader](https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle).

With vich bundle the src attribute will be :

```
src="{{ vich_uploader_asset(exposition, 'imageFile') | imagine_filter("livres")}}"
```

Comment: Ok thanks I'm going to look VichUploader